# About primary decomposition of $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I want to find the primary decomposition of $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ under multiplication group action. So I know 7 is a prime number so it is a group of order 6. So possibilities are $\mathbb{Z}_7^*\cong \mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$. However when I check the element $[a]\in \mathbb{Z}_7$ has order 6 by fermat's little theorem. I do not see how to decompose $\mathbb{Z}_7$ into $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$ though I am expecting it is supposed to happen.

Comment: $7 \neq 2 \cdot 3$.
You seem to be interested in the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ which is indeed $\mathbb{Z}_6$

Comment: The multiplicative group of $\Bbb Z_7$ is rather denoted by $\Bbb Z_7^*$. What element have you found as $[a]\in\Bbb Z_7$?

Comment: I found $\{[1],..,[6]\}=Z_7^{\star}$.

Comment: Ah, I thought, you realized that e.g. $[3]$ has order $6$... Also, Fermat's theorem doesn't state that the order of each element is the order of the group, but that it is a *divisor* of it.

Comment: Ah. That is what got me. I thought Fermat's little theorem says all elements relatively prime to 7 are order 6. Well my bad. Thanks.

Comment: However, $\Bbb Z_7^*$ is indeed cyclic, e.g. $[3]$ generates it ($3,\ {\tiny 9\equiv}2,\ {\tiny 6\equiv}-1,\ -3,\ -2,\ 1$.)

Comment: Yes. <[2]>=$Z[7]$ and <[3]>$\leq$ <[2]>.

Comment: No, $2$ has order $3$ as $8\equiv 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you found a primitive root in $\Bbb Z_7$, i.e. which generates its multiplicative group. 
Therefore, the multiplicative group $\Bbb Z_7^*$ is cylcic, hence $\cong\Bbb Z_6$.

Finally, the isomorphism $\Bbb Z_2\oplus\Bbb Z_3\ \to\ \Bbb Z_6$ can be given by
$$(a,b)\mapsto 3a+2b\,.$$

Comment: There is a theorem that $\mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_m \cong \mathbb{Z}_{nm}$ if and only if $\gcd(n,m)=1$. This shows that $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}_6$, so which one $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ is, is irrelevant.